# How is the kinetic energy change during a throttling process negligible?

Tags: thermodynamics

The throttling process is a constant enthalpy process, in which the pressure decreases. So,

h1 = h2

u1+p1v1 = u2+p2v2

If the pressure is decreasing and if we consider the Joule-Thomson coefficient to be such that the temperature is decreasing too(so internal energy, u will decrease), then the specific volume will increase. If the specific volume increases won't it cause a change in velocity and so the kinetic energy? Why is it said that there is a negligible change in kinetic energy in a throttling process?

Comment: That same source I gave you here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/35908/10902

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you. Ref :https://books.google.co.in/books?id=UQn0EW9xqhwC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=throttling+process+velocity+kinetic+energy+pipe&source=bl&ots=DhHgT63_hw&sig=ACfU3U2wYi3HSVksy4b9gdHYZkZmh8CTAg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN252q8MrpAhUsyDgGHd8qBSc4ChDoATAEegQICxAB#v=onepage&q=throttling%20process%20velocity%20kinetic%20energy%20pipe&f=false

Comment: A very good book, you should get much understanding from it.